# How do you put an element above another in mobile view only?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap 3.x and I have two divs of col-lg-6. Column X and Column Y.

On desktop view, Column X is on the left and Column Y is on the right.

How do I get it so that on smaller screen widths, Column Y is **stacked above** Column X?

Comment: Please Check this simple anser: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46533853/5236174

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you can put column Y before column X and play with floating by using `pull-right` or `pull-left`. Take a look on the snippet below.

```css
@media all and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .mobile .col-y {
    float: left !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container desktop">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-y pull-right">Y</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">X</div>
</div>

<div class="container mobile">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-y pull-right">Y</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">X</div>
</div>
```

You can also use just media query, without using `pull-right`. It's up to you and both variants are correct. I've used `col-xs-6` because the preview window is small, you should customize that.

Answer (score 1):

Very very simple:

Code it the way you want for mobile.

Y first,
X second.

`.col-xs-*` is for mobile screen, `.col-sm-*` for bigger screen

1. use `.col-xs-12` on X and Y, In order to stack Y above X on the mobile screen.
2. use `.col-sm-6` to have X and Y in one row for a bigger screen.
3. and make X: `.pull-left` and Y: `.pull-right` to have X-Y, left-right on bigger scren

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 pull-right">Y</div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 pull-left">X</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For those of us landing here via a Google search in the Bootstrap 4(+) days, as I did, the way this is done now is with the series of "order" classes.

Documentation [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#reordering)

Here is an example:

```
<div class="col-md-6 order-1 order-lg-0">
    <!-- at mobile I'm second -->
</div>

<div class="col-md-6 order-0 order-lg-1">
    <!-- at mobile I'm first -->
</div>
```

Note: this is a mobile first design standard so if you set an order at a smaller size it will apply to the larger unless overwritten thus the need for the "order-lg-<#>